# Looking for best practise for local and server data handling

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, sqlite

I've developed an android app which stores information about your courses in university. All data is stored locally in a sqlite3 database.
I want to expand the app and make it possible to share those course information between two or more users, so they can edit the same course and its information. The aim is that on both devices the course will be synchronized.
For this purpose I have setup a nodejs server with express (restful api) and mongoDB to store everything on the server.

My question is: What is the 'best-practise' for such a situation?
Should i drop the local sqlite database and always get the data from the server when i start the app?
Should i keep the local sqlite database and always synchronize it with the server mongoDB?
Should i drop the local sqlite database and cache data from the server until the server tells the app that it has got new/changed data?

I'm pretty new to web/server development.

With best regards,
Tak3r07

Answer (score 1):

For this task I think it's better to use a service created for this purpose like:

- http://pouchdb.com/ It enables applications to store data locally
  while offline, then synchronize it with CouchDB and compatible
  servers when the application is back online, keeping the user's data
  in sync no matter where they next login.
- https://www.firebase.com/ Data is stored as JSON, synced to all
  connected clients in realtime, and available when your app goes
  offline.

Comment: Thank you for this answere. Even tho as far as I've read, pouchdb does not provide a proper implementation for android. This has brought me to Couchbase Lite.